# Como forçar o download de um objeto de um AWS bucket S3 com PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-aws

Eu sei como fazer upload de um objeto para a AWS S3 Bucket desta forma:

```
try {
    $oClientAws->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'bucket_test',
        'Key'    => 'fileName.jpg',
        'Body'   => fopen('path/to/file/fileName.jpg', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ));            
} 
catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {}
```

Mas não sei como forçar o download de um objeto eu consigo usar `$oClientAws->GetObject (parametros ...)` e alterar o tipo de conteúdo do cabeçalho, mas isso apenas mostra o meu arquivo no navegador, mas não baixa o arquivo de fato.

Tem alguma forma correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Sem chance de ser duplicado, o meu é referente ao s3 da aws e não apenas de forçar o download de um arquivo que é bem simples. Mas beleza.

Comment: Exatamente, o content-type funciona mas o arquivo vem diretamente do bucket e não de um ftp, e para forçar o download de um ftp por exemplo devo dar um fread no final das alterações de cabeçalho ou seja existe de fato um caminho no diretório para o arquivo, mas no bucket está diretamente na aws, encontrei um método na API chamado saveTo(), que salva em um diretório o arquivo e isso vai ajudar, espero que eu tenha sido claro, utilizando o bucket da aws fica mais fácil entender a situação de não possuir o arquivo físico em um ftp. Abraços.

Comment: No cliente, com o saveTo() foi possível apenas no servidor pois deve ser informado a pasta que o mesmo deverá ser salvo, mas isso já me ajuda pois em seguida consigo ler e forçar o download e remover esse arquivo que foi salvo no servidor.

Comment: Votei por reabrir pois se trata do sistema S3. Não é uma duplicidade.

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não existe um parâmetro para forçar o download. O que você pode fazer é:

- Criar uma url sua, por exemplo, download.php, capturar o objeto da Amazon e usar um código fonte semelhante ao abaixo

  ```
  $result = $s3->getObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $bucket,
  'Key'    => $keyname
  ));
  header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
  echo $result['Body'];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

O autor obteve a resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31061085/1518921), importei para cá acaso ajude outros usuários.

Use a classe S3 standalone (que eu encontrei não é muito diferente da AWS SDK) com o `getObject`:

```
/**
* Get an object
*
* @param string $bucket Bucket name
* @param string $uri Object URI
* @param mixed $saveTo Filename or resource to write to
* @return mixed
*/
public static function getObject($bucket, $uri, $saveTo = false)
{
    $rest = new S3Request('GET', $bucket, $uri, self::$endpoint);
    if ($saveTo !== false)
    {
        if (is_resource($saveTo))
            $rest->fp =& $saveTo;
        else
            if (($rest->fp = @fopen($saveTo, 'wb')) !== false)
                $rest->file = realpath($saveTo);
            else
                $rest->response->error = array('code' => 0, 'message' => 'Unable to open save file for writing: '.$saveTo);
    }
    if ($rest->response->error === false) $rest->getResponse();

    if ($rest->response->error === false && $rest->response->code !== 200)
        $rest->response->error = array('code' => $rest->response->code, 'message' => 'Unexpected HTTP status');
    if ($rest->response->error !== false)
    {
        self::__triggerError(sprintf("S3::getObject({$bucket}, {$uri}): [%s] %s",
        $rest->response->error['code'], $rest->response->error['message']), __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }
    return $rest->response;
}
```

Fonte: https://aws.amazon.com/code/1448